# count the time am to pm

Tags: windows-phone-7, timer

I want to be able to count the time from pressing the start and until you press stop then it shall calculate the time that has passed in between.

I want it to use the clock as sourcetime. So if the clock is 06 AM when you press start and 06 PM when you stop i want it to give me how many hours gone by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Windows Phone 7, your application has virtually no chance of running for the entire amount of time.

This probably makes it easier for you, as you'd simply store a `DateTime` when you start it, and a `DateTime` when you stop it.

You can easily then, get a `TimeSpan` between the two, giving you the elapsed time. Off your `TimeSpan`, there is a property for `Hours`/`TotalHours`.

Comment: I have three buttons but how do i get it work when you have the start and end in different places: `        public void start_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void end_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void calc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan diff = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
            start.Text = diff;
        }`

Comment: Well for this to work regardless, you're going to need to store the Start Date and End Date in a file somewhere. That said, your exact question is something that is very basic in C#, so I'd suggest to read up on that first :)

Comment: You can see how i did in my own answer. The only thing that i did not get is how it display hours and minutes and not hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Because that's the default `ToString()` formatter. You can override it using [these formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee372287.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is how i made it;

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then i made it like this to calculate the difference:

```
TimeSpan diff = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
start.Text = diff.ToString();
```